# SSMS v19 and 20 not showing authentication window when connecting to always encrypted table

Tags: sql-server, ssms

We have a number of tables that have always encrypted columns. When I connect to these tables via SSMS v18 it brings up a authentication popup that lets me choose the account to use to connect to azure and then I am able to see the plain text data.

When I query the same table in SSMS v19 or v20 the authentication popup does not show and the query errors out saying I don't have access.

When I connect to the db in SSMS v18 I use the databasename,port when I use SSMS v19 or v20 I use databasename.mycompanyname.com,port. Not sure if this makes any difference or not?

How do I get this popup to work in SSMS v19 and/or v20?

There is the error

> Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 2
> Failed to decrypt column 'MyColumn'.
> Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 2
> Failed to decrypt a column encryption key using key store provider: 'AZURE_KEY_VAULT'. Verify the properties of the column encryption key and its column master key in your database. The last 10 bytes of the encrypted column encryption key are: 'AA-BB-CC-DD-EE-F7-60-A2-23-C7'.
> Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 2
> Retry failed after 4 tries. Retry settings can be adjusted in ClientOptions.Retry or by configuring a custom retry policy in ClientOptions.RetryPolicy.

Comment: To ask the obvious, you did [enable Always Encrypted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-query-columns-ssms?view=sql-server-ver16#en-dis) in your connection string, correct?

Comment: @ThomA the SSMS query window itself has the always encrypted checkbox checked

Comment: Some of the behaviours you describe can be attributed to underlying changes in SSMS. SSMS 19.1 migrated from System.Data.SqlClient to Microsoft.Data.SqlClient (v3) and SSMS 20 updated to use Microsoft.Data.SqlClient (v5). Ref: [SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) 19.1 and Recent Changes, Part 1](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/sql-server-management-studio-ssms-19-1-and-recent-changes-part-1/ba-p/3843500).

Comment: The connection options > Always Encrypted tab also exposed new controls "Enable secure enclaves" and "Enclave attestation protocol". Ref: [Prerequisites for running T-SQL statements using enclaves in SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-enclaves-query-columns?view=sql-server-ver16#prerequisites-for-running-t-sql-statements-using-enclaves-in-ssms). Have you checked that those options are set correctly for your target server(s)?